# OnClick() Functions not working when loaded through XML HttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, svg, xmlhttprequest

I have creating a XML HttpRequest that reloads a div content, by redrawing an SVG map in its place. Within the SVG map is the event triggers for the zoom, pan and reset javascript functions. Both the map and the javascript functions are written as Strings in Java

The JavaScript that is loaded also contains tooltip functions that work on hover, so the error is clearly with the onclick()

XML HttpRequest:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                               //select div with id map, replace this with ADMapYear.html and map as drawn in Eclipse/Java
                               document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                               eval(document.getElementById("scriptLoad").innerHTML);
                            }
                        };
                        xhttp.open("GET", "/ADMapYear.html/"+year_selected, true);
                        xhttp.send();


JavaScript:

"function reset() {\n" + 
                        "               for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {\n" + 
                        "                   transformMatrix[i] = origMatrix[i];\n" + 
                        "               }               \n" + 
                        "               var newMatrix = \"matrix(\"+ transformMatrix.join(' ') + \")\";\n" + 
                        "               matrixGroup.setAttributeNS(null, \"transform\", newMatrix); \n" + 
                        "          \n" + 
                        "           };"+

                        "function pan(dx, dy) {"+
                            "transformMatrix[4] += dx;"+
                            "transformMatrix[5] += dy;"+

                            "var newMatrix = \"matrix(\"+ transformMatrix.join(' ') + \")\";"+
                            "matrixGroup.setAttributeNS(null, \"transform\", newMatrix);"+
                        "}"+

                        "function zoom(scale) {"+
                            "for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {"+
                                "transformMatrix[i] *= scale;"+
                            "}"+

                            "transformMatrix[4] += (1-scale) * centerX;"+
                            "transformMatrix[5] += (1-scale)* centerY;"+

                            "var newMatrix = \"matrix(\"+ transformMatrix.join(' ') + \")\";"+
                            "matrixGroup.setAttributeNS(null, \"transform\", newMatrix);"+ 
                        "}"
```

SVG:

```
<path class=\"button\" onclick=\"pan(0,25)\" d=\"M25 5 l6 10 a20 35 0 0 0 -12 0z\" style= \"fill: black;\"/>\n" + 
                                "       <path class=\"button\" onclick=\"pan(25,0)\" d=\"M5 25 l10 -6 a35 20 0 0 0 0 12z\" style= \"fill: black;\" />\n" + 
                                "       <path class=\"button\" onclick=\"pan(0, -25)\" d=\"M25 45 l6 -10 a20, 35 0 0, 1 -12,0z\" style= \"fill: black;\"/>\n" + 
                                "       <path class=\"button\" onclick=\"pan(-25,0)\" d=\"M45 25 l-10 -6 a35 20 0 0 1 0 12z\" style= \"fill: black;\"/>\n" + 
                                "       \n" + 
                                "       <circle class=\"button\" cx=\"25\" cy=\"20.5\" r=\"3\" onclick=\"zoom(1.25)\" style= \"fill: black;\"/>\n" + 
                                "       <circle class=\"button\" cx=\"25\" cy=\"29.5\" r=\"3\" onclick=\"zoom(0.8)\" style= \"fill: black;\"/>\n" + 
                                "       \n" + 
                                "       <g>\n" + 
                                "           <rect class=\"button\" x=\"12\" y=\"50\" width =\"30\" height=\"15\" onclick=\"reset()\" fill=\"#464647\"/>\n" +
```

No error message appears, it just does not zoom, pan or reset on click

Answer (score 0):

I think thay doesn't because the function doesn't exist at the time of the binding. I suggest you to bind the function after that the XML HttpRequest returns

edit: 
Also, you put the response in an element, then eval another element:

```
document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
eval(document.getElementById("scriptLoad").innerHTML);
```

Should become:

```
document.getElementById("map").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
eval(document.getElementById("map").innerHTML);
```

Also, i would suggest you to do not use eval, as this creates vulnerabilities in your code. In order to avoid eval, you could send in the HttpResponse a script file and add it to your code.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately this hasn't worked

Comment: Just to be sure that we found the problem, are the functions ''zoom" and 'pan' visible after the request? I mean, if you call them from console they works?

Comment: I just ran it again, and it states that zoom is undefined in the console

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with a HTTPRequst not working when called from OnClick. I solved it by putting the element being clicked (a button) inside  tags.